# Format String as an email in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I feel like what I need done is pretty simple. Basically, if you type an email address into a cell in Excel and hit "Enter", it'll automatically turn blue and underline. Then, if you hover over it, a tooltip pops up reading "mailto:email@example.com". I want to accomplish the exact same thing, but instead of typing the String, VBA puts it into a cell.

I currently have VBA inserting into a cell correctly, but it won't turn into that "mailto" format afterwards.
Here's a really basic version of what I have in my code:

```
    Dim Email As String
    Email = Cells(7, "B").Value
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "D").Value = Email
```

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a Cell.Value to a hyperlink?

Comment: I initially thought that that's what I wanted. I just felt like since a hyperlink opens up a webpage for you that the "mailto" functionality was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real basics of it are :

```
Cells(1, "A").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    "mailto:taco@gmail.com", TextToDisplay:="taco@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Or just specify `Anchor:=Range("A1")` to one-line it.

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, maybe your new i don't know. But if you ever have question like this that are "simple" just hit Record Macro, do what you want to do, then stop recording it and look at the code. :)